# Can an app's installation and updating be whitelisted?

Tags: windows

I have an app that was built in C#. The app is for internal use only. Some of the machines that it needs to run on are locked down so only the admin can install apps. This means that the IT guy needs to come and install the app and any updates. The app will get updates frequently, perhaps daily. This will end up being a PITA for everybody.

Is there a way that the administrator can white list certain apps to be able to be installed and updated without admin privileges?

Comment: It is not the admin’s responsibility to make sure your app can install and update without admin permissions. It is your responsibility as a developer to write software that is compliant with industry standards. Is there a reason your software has to have admin permissions? Most do not.

Comment: An app cannot be installed without admin permissions. (Unless it can, but that's a different story). I'd use ''runas'' for the installation process. This needs to be tweaked, but can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As "Appleoddity" stated, WHY does app need Admin rights to install. Who is the developer? Does App needs access to the parts of the system that only Admins have access to? You are giving us to few info.

Does installer for the app requires elevation (does icon have a shield) or does the app simply fails to install if it is installed without Admin rights?

1) If installer doesn't require elevation but simply fails then my aproach would be to find out what the app is doing during installation. If it writes in Program Files then give users write rights on that dir. If it writes to specific registry key, give users rights to write to that key ...

2) If installer requires elevation, right from the start then does installer support quiet installation? If yes, why not use "GPO preferences \ Task Scheduler" to install the app during startup process.

But you are giving us little to go on. We need more info, much more. Is it MSI installer or executable?

OK, look, simple answer is "NO, app installation can not be whitelisted" but that doesn't automatically mean it can't be installed without Admin going to that machine.